# SessionStorage Javascript =/= PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, sessionstorage

I wrote in SessionStorage a variable "level" with value "4" with Javascript.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('level', 4);
```

But when I want to read it with PHP, it makes error :/

```
echo $_SESSION["level"];
```

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zx6o.png)

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: PHP (and it's sessions) lives on the server. Javascript lives in the browser.

Comment: As your own title suggests, javascript SessionStorage has **nothing** to do with PHP sessions.

Comment: You are looking for cookies, they share between JS and PHP

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript session storage has absolutely nothing in common with the PHP session. The former is owned by the client (browser) and can be accessed only in the client context, while the later exists on the server and it's connected to the browsing session, usually through a cookie.

You need to do more reading to understand how they both work, but long story short, *they have nothing in common*.

For JavaScript, in browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

For PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Answer (score 1):

sessionStorage is browser's local memory. It does not directly sync with server side code as you are trying with $_SESSION.