# Access javascript sessionStorage in php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session, session-storage

In my Laravel project's `app.js`, I have this:

```
let isModalShown = sessionStorage.getItem('book_modal_has_shown');
    if(!isModalShown) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("book_modal_has_shown", "true");
        $('#show_nudge_modal').modal('show');
```

This acts like a client-side check to stop the modal from coming out if the modal has already appeared (in the previous requests).

In my `Controller`, I have this:

```
$unreadBook = Book::getRandomUnreadBook();
return view('home')->with(['book' => $unreadBook]);
```

The problem is even if the modal does not appear on the client side, `Book::getRandomUnreadBook()` causes the database fetch operation. I want to add a server side check also to stop this useless database access.

Comment: Use a session variable?

Comment: PHP cannot access browser APIs like sessionStorage. See almost duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888221/sessionstorage-javascript-php

Comment: Stackoverflow is so special. The comments above prove the inability for people on here to think fluidly and figure out exactly what you're asking. People here are extremely literal.

What you want to do is use ajax to send an http request when the modal opens. And a seperate laravel route that returns only json. then put that data in the modal.

Comment: you can't access the browser's session storage, so as Death By Penguin suggests, you need to find another way to inform the server that it should not carry out the operation. The only way for the browser to send messages to the server is via a HTTP request - so either a postback or AJAX request. It's not clear what the flow of your program is...when does this controller method run? It must run in response to some sort of request from the browser...so you either have to prevent the request from happening, or if it must run, send a value as a parameter to tell it not to run that specific query

Comment: Now of course, the course of action you take (prevent request, or set a parameter) can be based on the value from the session storage, but the PHP cannot directly read that value, hence the need for this intermediate step.

Comment: @ADyson The controller code is executed when browser requests `/home`. You said _send value as a parameter to tell it not to run that specific query_. Where should I do this?

Comment: "The controller code is executed when browser requests /home"...is this happening _before_ your modal pops up? i.e. is this the code which renders the page in which the JavaScript code runs? If that's true then you have no way to prevent the query from running, because the page doesn't even exist yet, so it can't possibly read anything from the user's storage. Perhaps you'd be better storing this information server-side, also that way it can be made to persist between sessions and also across the user's different browsers and devices.

Comment: 1. browser requests `\home`, which are routed to `HomeController`'s index method
2. the `HomeController` has only two lines of code that you saw in the description
3. after fetching a random book from the database, the Controller passes that book to the view
4. the modal is defined in this view

Comment: ok so as I explained, if you're running this code before the JavaScript which checks the session storage then obviously you have no way to prevent it running based on that value. So you either a) just accept the performance hit (you didn't say whether this is causing / is anticipated to cause a noticeable problem?), or b) re-design things so that this data is stored server-side instead.

Comment: @ADyson thanks man. makes total sense